# Would the addition of Citric and Phosphoric Acid or Potassium Carbonate to agricultural water supply result in health/safety concerns?

Tags: acid-base, food-chemistry, toxicity

I am doing a small greenhouse project for fun. As a side benefit of this project, I was hoping to consume the food that I will be producing. I have been checking all of the products that I will be using for safety in this application.

However, there are two products I am not entirely certain of. They are:

- Root Farm pH Down
- Root Farm pH Up

[image]

I'm not entirely certain of the ingredients. However, on the back of each, there is a warning label which indicates that it contains the following:

**Root Farm pH Up**

- Potassium Carbonate

**Root Farm pH Down**

- Phosphoric Acid
- Citric Acid

My recollection of high school chemistry is limited, and so I was looking for advice on the following:

- Would it be safe for me to add these products to the water my vegetables will be using?
- Are there any potential "side effects" of adding this solution that
  could cause health concerns when eating the plants?
- Should I be staying away from this solution and using a different
  product for any reason?

Answer (score 2):

There are many levels and contexts of safety. Responsible chemists would comment just small part of it. Explicitly, users of CH SE site avoid to comment medical aspects of safety and health.

There are no safe nor harmful nor dangerous chemicals. Their doses or concentrations or exposure patterns make them safe, harmful or dangerous. Water (a propagator of drinking extreme daily volumes died because of that) or table salt will kill you if swallowed in large quantity, while sub-milligram amount of potassium cyanide is harmless.

Make the decision if it is safe yourself. Generally, any solution, especially concentrated, is dangerous to eyes, concentrated carbonates also attack skin, making it soapy, like [washing soda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate#Washing_soda) as sodium carbonate does.

---

[**Potassium carbonate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_carbonate) $\ce{K2CO3}$:

- Carbonate creates in the irrigation water with proper dosing a bicarbonate  pH buffer ($\ce{HCO3-(aq) + CO2(aq)}$), similar as humans have in their blood.
- Potassium is a part of fertilizers, is essential for plants.
- It is important nutrition (bananas are famous in that), .
- Bicarbonates are used in baking powders, forming carbonates.
- Potassium carbonate is directly used in industrial processing of most of world cocoa to alkalize cocoa beans/mass/powder. If you see dark cocoa powder, it is the processed one due darkened oxidized polyphenols. The similar for chocolates, as very most uses this processed cocoa.

[**Citric acid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid):

- You consume it in citruses.
- Salts of citric acid are essential part of the citrate cycle, the central part of aerobic metabolism.

**[Phosphoric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid) $\ce{H3PO4}$**

- Diluted one is present in Coca-cola.
- It's salts are essential nutrition for plants, a part of fertilizers
- Phosphates, respectively their bound forms in DNA, RNA, ATP, phospholipides, milk casein are essential nutrition and common part of food.
- Dihydrogen phosphates are often a part of ionic drink formulas.

Comment: I applaud your bravery! ;)